# Typography or symbols used in text

Tags: symbols, footnotes, typography, footmisc

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

$\therefore$ Therefore % Used often in math text

$\because$ Because % Used often in math text

\textreferencemark\ Reference/Note % Used often in footnote

\textdagger\ or $\ddagger$ Footer  % Used often in footnote

\end{document}
```

[image]

Are there any other examples you use?

Comment: Examples of what? Why don't you look at the symbol lists? There are thousands! 'Almost...'??

Comment: @cfr, yes there are thousands but many do not have meaning. I wanted to ask both for the meaning and for the symbol that is currently used.

Comment: I wanted to know if the professional users like you and the amateurs like me did not know.

Comment: Therefore and Because are math symbols and used in logic math sentences. The other three I don't think that have a meaninig in math and anyone can use it as he wants.

Comment: @koleygr I added **math text**.

Comment: Yes... you did. But correct it to say "Used often in math text" and "used often in footnote" (Almost means "not exactly but close.." or something like this that doesn't make sense there) etc. BUT: On this community, questions that are based on opinion etc are deleted or closed and so I think you will not find a "good symbol usage style" question. For me there is no such thing. Every author can use his style or some symbols in his own way for his specific wants. Even math symbols can be redefined for the purposes of a book (but it is not a good idea if not really important reason).

Comment: @koleygr, I think you are partially right. But I started writing a book. And I want to follow the international typography rules (if any).

Comment: I'm not a professional user, whatever that means. And I still don't know what you want examples of. There are thousands of symbols for use in maths and text which have meaning. I was not referring to purely decorative items, which I would not count as symbols. Symbols symbolise things. Hence, they all must have meanings.

Comment: Just look at the comprehensive symbol list (which includes some non-symbols, too, but mostly symbols). `texdoc comprehensive`. What else is there to say?

Comment: Math rules and symbols can be found by googling for example "math therefore symbol"... The only point I see for discussion is that there exist systems like ISO and other that sometimes remove or add some symbols and I don't really know how to help you (even if I am a physicist)... But my opinion is that if you are not sure about using or not using a symbol you have just to think if it makes your book easier to be read or harder. Just define it and use it, if not sure it is a common symbol. If we don't talk about math my opinion is that simplicity has to be over complexed beauty...

Comment: @cfr, your comment is beautiful too.